# Compressed routes in HERE

Tags: here-api

We're novices using this SDK. We are showing a Map polyline with this method:

```
ArrayList<GeoCoordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.53032, 13.37409));
    coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.5309, 13.3946));
    coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.53894, 13.39194));
    coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.54014, 13.37958));
```

We get these track points from a collection of Firestore. The problem is that we have routes with 60000 track points (lat/lng). Does exist a way to get that from a compressed object with all the route?
We need that the route requires the minor data possible from Firestore storage.

Thanks!!

Comment: "Compressed" in what sense? Getting a route is a sort of **de-compression** already. It expands two points into a much longer list of points.

Comment: If I have the encoded polyline from Google Algorithm, could I decoded that with HERE SDK? How?

Comment: "Google Algorithm" - Google probably has thousands of algorithms, but I don't see what Google has to do with Here? They're two distinct companies? But I also wonder whether it is really relevant to your problem. I think you mean: "I have 60.000 geographical coordinates in a single route, from an external source, and I want to _compress_ it somehow". And I guess with "compress" you don't mean "gzip it". But you have to tell us what you mean, we really can't guess

Comment: With "compressed" I refer to do something like Google does with the encoded Polylines. I need to storage in Firestore something more "little" than 60000 coordinates hardcoded, so I would like to find how to encode the coordinates, with a HERE algorithm that I can decoded in my app. Is https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline that I need?

Comment: I think you are missing my point. We cannot tell if a particular **lossy** compression algorithm works for you. As I mentioned before, the ultimate compression algorithm is to just remove the middle 59.998 points and recalculate the route later. I don't understand what you mean by "do something like Google does with the encoded Polylines". Google is a very, very big company. It does many things with coordinates. The code snippet shown is anything but compressed, it's very verbose

Comment: I´m going to store the encode polyline (generated by Google) in Firestore, and get it from the app, decoded it (with Google SDK),  and show with HERE the coordinate list getted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably not only creating a polyline, but to create a route. If such a route comes from a different vendor, you can use the `RoutingEngine`'s `importRoute()` feature. It allows to set a large list of coordinates. From the resulting `Route` object you can get the polyline as property.

Creating such a list of coordinates is not dependent on the HERE SDK in any way, except that you need to create a `GeoCoordinates` instance for each point. Accessing such data from Firestore and then iterate over the data in a loop should do the trick.